# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `nice_actions`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using WAMP server on Windows 10. I'm new to Laravel and I have this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `nice_actions`)

Here is the MySQL in `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

and in `.env` file I have this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=laravel 
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: run composer dump-autoload php artisan config:cache php artisan clear:cache

Comment: check php.ini for mysql.default_socket, maybe use that instead of by IP

Comment: thank you @Leo_Kelmendi it works !

Answer (score 1):

try to run `php artisan config:cache`